# How to generate deb package without compiling

Tags: debian, dpkg, debian-installer, deb

I generated a package with the following command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc --source-option=--include-binaries --source-option=-isession
```

Now I have figured out that my `package.install` file is wrong and I have corrected it. The question is how can I generate the deb package again without compiling the whole program?

I try to execute the above command with the `-nc` option that means "Do not clean" but it does not generated the deb again.

I also try to execute `fakeroot debian/rules binary` (as described here https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#idm1642)

but it doesn't generate the deb. How can check if the deb is correct with the corresponding files inside (that I have corrected in the `package.install` file)?

with this command:

```
ar p mypackage.deb data.tar.xz | tar xJ
```

And then follow the tree source and see if the new files are copied in its corresponding folders.

Comment: You can try `fakeroot debian/rules install`, but it may not work depending on what's in the `rules` file.

Comment: If I run that command I only get the following output `dh install --buildsystem=cmake` and it does not generate the deb package

Comment: Skip straight to section 4 - http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/#AEN88 .